# SolR DIH file concatenation

Tags: mysql, solr, dih

I want to use SolR DataImport Handler to index candidates stored in a database along with content of files linked to these candidates.

I have one database table containing the list of candidates and another table containing the list of file paths linked to the candidate.

What I need is to:

1. index the candidate data - *pretty easy...*
2. loop through the file list - *I managed to do this as well...*
3. extract the content of the file (being pdf, doc, xml, html, etc... - *This part is done*
4. **group the content of all files within one content field for indexing**

This is actually where I'm stuck!
I tried various options but the system is only indexing the content of the first file.
I tried playing with a javascript global variable, although this kind of work doesn't seem to be the best solution...

Find hereafter my dih.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <dataConfig>
     <script><![CDATA[
      var globalContent = '';

      function processFile(row) {
        var text = row.get('text');
        if (text == null) text = '';
        else globalContent += ' ' + text;

        row.remove('text');
        row.remove('content');

        row.put('content', globalContent);
        return row;
      }
     ]]></script>

     <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"    name="dbs" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" user="login" password="password" />
     <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="fds" /> 

     <document name="ListOfCandidates">
      <entity name="candidats" datasource="dbs" query="select * from candidates">
       <field column="id_candidat" name="id_candidat" />
       <field column="name"        name="lastname"    />
       <field column="first_name"  name="firstname"   />

       <entity name="ListOfFiles" 
               query="SELECT distinct cd.id_document, cd.filepath 
                  FROM candidat_document cd
                  WHERE cd.id_candidat = '${candidats.id_candidat}'">
        <entity name="file" 
                processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
                url="/some/folder/${ListOfFiles.filepath}" 
                dataSource="fds" 
                format="text" 
                onError="skip"
                transformer="script:processFile">
          <field column="text" name="text" />
        </entity>                   
       </entity>
      </entity>
     </document>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your **row** object contains all the information accumulated through the individual entry of **candidats**. Have you tried just populating a special field inside that **row** that accumulates the text.

So, exactly what you are doing, but store it in **row** instead of global variable.